# How to show that $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{1-x^2}$ is convex and has a minimum value

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

I want to show that  $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{1-x^2}$ is convex on the interval $]-1,1[$. How do I have to proceed?

I did take the derivative of the function which is 
$f'(x) = \frac{2x\sqrt{\cos x }}{(1-x^2)^2}-\frac{\sin x}{2\sqrt{\cos x}(1-x^2)}$

For a function to be convex I need to show that it is increasing on the interval?

I'm a little stuck to proof that rigorously. Thanks for your help!

Comment: the second derivative must be positive

Comment: Hi, thanks for your  answer. On the Interval  ]-1,1[ or what? It depends on the values whether the derivative is positive or negative.

Comment: if $f''(x)>0$ for $x\in(-1;1)$ then $f$ is convex on $(-1;1)$

Comment: the second derivative of that thing is huge. And then just check limit cases 1 and negative 1 ?

Comment: you don't have to calculate limits, just show that $f''(x)>0$; also you're right, the second derivative is complicated, I think there may be a simpler way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f$ be given by

$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{1-x^2}$$

for $|x|<1$.  Then, the first derivative of $f$ is

$$f'(x)=\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}}{2(1-x^2)}\left(\frac{4x}{1-x^2}-\tan x\right) \tag 1$$

From $(1)$ we can write

$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac12\left(\frac{4x}{1-x^2}-\tan x\right) \tag 2$$

whereupon differentiating both sides of $(2)$ and solving for $f''(x)$ reveals that

$$f''(x)=\frac{\left(f'(x)\right)^2}{f(x)}+f(x)\left(\frac{4(1+x^2)}{(1-x^2)^2}-\sec^2 x\right)$$

It is evident that $f(x)>0$ and $\left(f'(x)\right)^2\ge 0$ for $|x|<1$.  We will now show that the term $\left(\frac{4(1+x^2)}{(1-x^2)^2}-\sec^2 x\right)$ is positive thereby establishing that $f''(x)> 0$.

Recall that the sine function satisfies the inequality

$$|\sin x|\le |x| \tag 2$$

From $(2)$ it is easy to show that for $|x|\le 1$

$$\cos x\ge \sqrt{1-x^2} \tag 3$$

Using $(3)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{4(1+x^2)}{(1-x^2)^2}-\sec^2 x\right) &\ge \left(\frac{4(1+x^2)}{(1-x^2)^2}-\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{3+5x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}\\\\
&>0
\end{align}$$

Since $f''(x)>0$, $f$ is convex on $-1<x<1$.

Since $f$ is even and convex, it attains it minimum at $x=0$ where we have $f(0)=1$.

Comment: Seems good now!

Comment: @egreg Thanks! Very much appreciative.

Comment: You can also note that  $f$ is continuous and positive on (-1,1) and tends to $\infty$ as $|x|\to 1$, so if $0<a<1$ where $a<|x|<1\to f(x)>f(0)$ then $\min \{f(x) : |x|\leq a\}$ is the minimum $f(x)$ over $(-1,1)$. Of course this $f$ is also convex and even so it must be minimum at $x=0$.

Comment: @user254665 I believe that the main task was to show that $f$ is convex.  The minimum is a consequence only.

Comment: Yes indeed. I was just thinking of more general cases. The convexity was the harder part.